# Uploading image to S3 (boto + GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, boto

I'm trying to get s3 (using boto) setup with my GAE python app to store images uploaded by users. Currently I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/phyzikz/project/boto/s3/key.py", line 936, in set_contents_from_file spos = fp.tell()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tell'
```

I'm at a loss for why this is happening – the file uploaded should be a png. Here's the code that makes the upload:

```
class Settings(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('settings.html')

    def post(self):
        image = self.request.get('image')

        if image:
            connection = S3Connection('<ak>','<sak>')
            bucket = connection.create_bucket('<s3bucket>')
            k = Key(bucket)
            k.key = '/pictures/users/'+ str(self.user.key().id())
            k.set_contents_from_file(image)
```

If it helps, while debugging it worked beautifully when substituting set_contents_from_file(image) with set_contents_from_string('some string'). I must be missing something simple. Here's the html:

```
<form method='post' action='/settings' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='image'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

disclaimer: I'm new to both python and SO (this is my first question!) Any edits to improving the phrasing of the question if necessary would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to wrap image in a StringIO instance so it looks like a file object

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = "123"
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> y = StringIO(x)
>>> y.tell()
0
>>>
```

So in your case you would

```
k.set_contents_from_file(StringIO(image))
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this worked! It might also be worth noting for others that after trying this I found it also works with `k.set_contents_from_string(image)` without using StringIO too.

Comment: @phyzikz: It doesn't work with **k.set_contents_from_string(image)**, after uploading on s3, you can see size of object is in bytes as it contains only string...so it's not worthy

Answer (score 0):

If you can put the code (in the method: `set_contents_from_file` inside the `Key` class ) where you have defined or assigned `fp`, we can help better. But, looking at the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tell'`, it is quite clear that `fp` is not a file object. It is a string object, hence the error. As you are new to SO, first try to correct the code yourself, then, if you ae still not getting it resolved, you can paste the code you are using to change `fp` to a file object.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. The method is part of the boto s3 package (https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/key.py - line 847). As you said it's clear the fp is not a file object, but given the simplicity of the html and request, i can't figure out why it's a string and not the png i selected.

Comment: As I can see there in line 847, the `fp` object is passed by the caller. There is not a problem in line 847. The problem is with `fp`. Can you somehow look into your code and paste the part where you have assigned a value to `fp`? You can use `print fp, type(fp)` to check what `fp` is.

Comment: repr(fp) gives me a screen full of text: `'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xc1...'`. `fp` in my case is the variable `image` that gets passed in via the post form and I pass in to the `set_contents_from_file` method. Does that help?

Comment: I am opening a file in my current working directory and this is what I get:-
`>>> fp=open('diff.diff')`
`>>> print fp`
`<open file 'diff.diff', mode 'r' at 0x03CC96A8>`
`>>> print type(fp)`
`<type 'file'>`

You should also see the output of `type(fp)` as a file object. Dont use repr for that